# 404 error , Get Object or 404 django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Hey guys i have made a blog website in which if i type in the number beside like this: blog/1, I should get the first blog or i should get a 404 error! but i only get the 404 error whereas i have the blogs! My project name is portfolio-project and the urls.py for it look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings

from django.conf.urls.static import static

import blog.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', blog.views.home, name='home'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And then it goes to blog.urls, and it looks like:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='allblogs'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

as i put blog/1 It goes to the views.detail file which looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog

def home(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'blogs':blogs})

def detail(request, blog_id):
    detailblog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'blog':detailblog})
```

Ok, So according to this i should go to the details.html and it has

{{ blog.title }}

But i dont see anything but an 404 error!

Comment: Could you make sure your first blog has id 1? Did you create a blog post and delete it before your current first one? You can find the id using `./manage.py shell` or open the post in admin section and check url.

Comment: first of all I am agree with @RamkishoreM and secondly your url points to `blog/1/` not `blog/1` you have added trailing slash in urlpattern

Comment: @Ramkishire M I have made 2 blog post for testing and I get same error

Comment: @Gahan I have already tried the thing you said I tried in both cases but still I get error

Comment: Are you able to render a list of posts on the home page? Link to detail page from home page using `{% url 'blog:detail' blog.id %}`. First add namespace to blog on main urls.py `path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog'))`

Comment: Where should add the {% url 'blog:detail' blog.id %} say me where I should add this and I will add the url pattern as you said but should I make any changes to add this or just add this and delete nothing from my code?

Comment: Your question is getting to broad. I suggest you go through the django tutorial fully.

Comment: Yes I am able to render a list of posts on the home page, I need the detail.HTML because I want a 'see more' option which gets to a page with full details of the blog

Comment: can you please say me why my code is wrong because i take django tutorial on udemy and he did the same i did but he has got no errors !

Comment: In your home view, you can display the blog ids with something like `{% for blog in blogs %}{{blog.id}}, {% endfor %}`. You'll probably find that you don't have a blog with `id=1` in the database. Then you can use the URL `localhost:8000/blog/x/` where `x` is an id that actually exists.

Comment: @Alasdair i actually have made a for loop in the home.html for rendering blogs i need to make a option such as "See More" When people click on it they should see the full info of the blog and the url needs to be like: blog/1/. But i am not able to get that. can you please say me why my code is wrong because i take django tutorial on udemy and he did the same i did but he has got no errors !

Comment: Your question is about the 404 on the detail page. To solve that, you need to find out the ids, which you could do by adding the loop as I suggested. Your question doesn't show `home.html` so we can't help with that.

Comment: Actually there is no work for the home.html here, i am only trying to go to the detail.html through the url so home.html doesnt have anything 
 to do here

Comment: I am still getting the 404 error

Comment: No, I can't edit your project for you. As I said before, if `localhost:8000/blog/1/` doesn't work, that's because you don't have any blogs with `id=1`. You need to use a URL for an id that does exist (maybe `localhost:8000/blog/2/`). I've given you a suggestion of a loop you can use to find out which ids exist in your database. I can't help you beyond that.

Comment: Hey @Alasdair thanks alot that worked for me! i dont have a blog-id 1 but instead i have my blog-ids being started from 2 that is the 1st blog id is 2 and the 2nd blog id is 3! How can i make them clear with 1,2,3,etc

Comment: @AlasdairThat happens because i have deleted the 1st blog! When i add a new blog it gets added to next blog like after 2nd blog it gets added to the 3rd blog but not the empty 1st! How can i add a blog in the first one rather than adding it to the next added blog

Comment: Your database assigns ids automatically, don’t worry about 'filling the gaps' for missing ids.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: you may also be interested in creating a slug field instead of using ids (once you get past the basics). https://keyerror.com/blog/automatically-generating-unique-slugs-in-django That way the internal id's are not exposed to the viewer and you get some nicer urls depending on the application of course. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Comment: Sure, I will check them out